# Update view in response to web service requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I'm fairly new to MVC and web programming at all. I need to solve one problem.

Let's say I have complete and working mvc app, web services (it might be anything - wcf, servicestack, web api...) and mobile apps (iOS, Android) working with my web service. Now when I'm on my Admin page is there a way for me update this admin page without having to reload it in response to web service requests when my mobile clients send one.

I don't want to ask my database for changes every few seconds though. I really want this flow:

I'm looking at my admin page -> Mobile app is sending a request (for example if user clicked a button or changed position) -> Web service gets the request -> ???? -> Data on my admin page changes.

Edit: Ok. Why it's always like this ? You look for an answer for long time. Then you ask a question and few minutes later you find possible solution. What I've already found is server side js events, websockets and long polling. Am I heading in the right direction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is http://signalr.net/

Answer (score 0):

For ServiceStack you can get real-time updates with [Server Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events). You can use the [C#/.NET ServerEvents Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-Server-Events-Client) with Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android to handle Server Push events on iOS and Android.